# Using cut and sed command at the same time in a script

Tags: shell-script, sed, cut

I have the following code in a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# gives summary of my buyings in the report.txt file

echo Here is the summary of your purchases:
echo =========================================
echo

# /dev/stdin is the standard input, i.e. the file
cat /dev/stdin | cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort && sed -n '2 p' /dev/stdin
```

So what I want is to print the 2nd and 3rd fields with space as delimiter and also print the second line of report.txt using `sed`. So how can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

The contents of my report.txt are:

```
Jakaria Books 5
Sakib Khata 3
Afzal Pen 12
Sharif Colorpen 2
Sakib Eraser 1
Sharif Sharpner 1
```

I edited my script as suggested and now it's the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# gives summary of my buyings in the report.txt file

echo Here is the summary of your purchases:
echo =========================================

# /dev/stdin is the standard input, i.e. the file
cat /dev/stdin | cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort | sed -n '2 p'
```

I run my script as `cat report.txt | ./summary` where `summary` is my script file name. Now the output is `Books 5`.

Apart from printing the 2nd and 3rd fields I also want to print the 2nd line of the report.txt, i.e. the output should be the following:

```
Books 5
Colorpen 2
Eraser 1
Khata 3
Pen 12
Sharpner 1
Sharif Sharpner 1
```

Comment: I assume you run this script like: `/path/to/script < report.txt` ?

Comment: Please add some sample from `report.txt`

Comment: You say you want to print the 2nd line of report.txt, but the sample report.txt's 2nd line is "Sakib Khata 3", which doesn't show up in your sample output.

Comment: Not knowing which 2nd line you meant, I updated my answer to show a `sed`-only option (plus the existing `|sort`).

Comment: My answer does exactly what you want since the beginning, but you don't seem to have seen it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chained on the `sed` command with `&&` you told the shell to run that command separately. That left the `cat ... cut ... sort` output alone and then *also* printed the 2nd line, without any cutting.

If you want to print only the second (sorted) line of input, change it to:

```
cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort | sed -n 2p
```

There's no need to repeat /dev/stdin, as both `cut` and `sed` will read stdin when you don't provide an input file.

---

To print the 2nd and 3rd space-delimited fields from a file, as well as print the entire 2nd line, you could do it all within sed:

```
sed -e 2p -e 's/^[^ ]* //' < report.txt | sort
```

This tells sed two execute two programs:

- `p`rint line 2, and
- `s`earch and replace: from the beginning of the line, zero or more non-space characters, followed by a space ... with: (nothing)

When run on your updated sample input, I get:

```
Books 5
Colorpen 2
Eraser 1
Khata 3
Pen 12
Sakib Khata 3
Sharpner 1
```

... since `Sakib Khata 3` is the 2nd line of the file.

Comment: I just updated my thread with more info. Can you kindly check it again? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents of `/dev/stdin` to a variable:

```
content=$(cat)
echo "$content" | cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort
echo "$content" | sed -n '2p'
```

`cat` defaults to reads from `stdin`.

Example:

```
(
  content=$(cat);
  echo "$content" | cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort;
  echo "$content" | sed -n '2p'
) < <(echo -e "a b c\nd e f\ng h i\n")


b c
e f
h i
d e f
```

---

**Update:**

Example from your edited question

```
echo 'Jakaria Books 5
Sakib Khata 3
Afzal Pen 12
Sharif Colorpen 2
Sakib Eraser 1
Sharif Sharpner 1' | (
    content=$(cat);
    echo "$content" | cut -d ' ' --fields=2,3 | sort;
    echo "$content" | sed -n '2p'
)

Books 5
Colorpen 2
Eraser 1
Khata 3
Pen 12
Sharpner 1
Sakib Khata 3
```

Comment: The `cat` utility will read from standard input by default if no filename is given to it.

Comment: cool ! edited..